# How to remove a VLAN tag from a VSwitch (VSW) in LDom OVM SPARC

Tags: solaris, vlan, sparc, vswitch

I have a OVM SPARC 3.x server and one of its switches is set with a vlan tag.

In the example below the VSW has a VID of 200. How do I remove the tag?

I cannot remove the vswitch, as other guests are using the untagged vlan.

> root@my-server:/# ldm ls -l -o network rdom-115-45 NAME
>   rdom-115-45
>
> MAC
>       00:34:19:ee:31:83
>
> VSW
>       NAME             MAC               NET-DEV   ID   DEVICE     LINKPROP   DEFAULT-VLAN-ID PVID VID                  MTU   MODE
>   INTER-VNET-LINK
>       192.168.115.0_24 00:22:4f:fe:26:e1 net0      0    switch@0   phys-state 1               1    200                  1500         on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the vlan tag you need to set the vswitch as follows, explicitly setting vid= to empty

> ldm set-vswitch **vid=** net-dev=net0 linkprop=phys-state
>   inter-vnet-link=on 192.168.115.0_24

This will leave all the other vswitch settings as before, removing just the VID value

> root@my-server:/# ldm ls -l -o network rdom-115-45 NAME
>   rdom-115-45
>
> MAC 00:34:19:ee:31:83
>
> VSW NAME MAC NET-DEV ID DEVICE LINKPROP DEFAULT-VLAN-ID PVID VID MTU MODE
>   INTER-VNET-LINK 192.168.115.0_24 00:22:4f:fe:26:e1 net0 0 switch@0 phys-state 1 1 200 1500 on